# Changes to info window layout are not reflected on map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have a Google Fusion Table and am plotting its data on a Google Map using the Google Maps API.

Initially I changed the info window layout and this was reflected in my version of the map that resides on its own domain.

Subsequent changes to the info window layout are not showing up though.

However, when viewing the map view within the fusion tables editor, the info window does indeed show all of the changes made. It's just my version that uses the API that isn't getting updated.

This is the info window layout HTML that I have written:

```
<div class='googft-info-window' style='font-family: sans-serif'>
<h4 style="font-size: 16px; margin: 0;">{restaurant}</h4>
<span style="color:#999; font-size: 12px;text-transform:uppercase;">{postcode}</span>
<a href='{website}' target='_blank'>{website}</a><br><br>
Recommended by: <a href='{review_link}' target='_blank'>{review}</a><br>
"{excerpt}"
</div>
```

As you can see it's just plain HTML so I don't think that is the issue. It seems the API is failing to show the info window layout changes. Everything else is working as it should and updating as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you specifying a template ID in your JavaScript? Each map tab has its own info window template. You can get its ID with **Tools > Publish** and looking at the resulting URL's *tmplt* parameter. This article has more details:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/style_and_template_ids